# Correct way to call WebApi RTM from an mvc4 application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So there is a heap of examples around but finding ones that are relevant to the rtm bits seems to be a little harder to find.

I have 2 projects one is an WebApi & the other is MVC4 .net 4.5 application.

I want to make a make an update to an item

I have a controller within my API that does something like

```
    [HttpPut]
    public MyModel Update(MyModel model)
    {
        //make update
        return model;
    }
```

Is this correct? should I be using a HttpResponseMessage instead of just using my MyModel class? I want to return the correct httpstatus details as much as possible as I am wanting to open up this api to 3rd parties not just my application

Calling this api from my mvc application from my controller how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beste way is to use HttpResponseMessage like this:

```
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage Update(MyModel model)
{
    if(notfound)
    {
      return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }

    //make update
    return this.Request.CreateResponse<MyModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, Model);;
}
```

I mostly use [EasyHttp](http://nuget.org/packages/EasyHttp) if I want want to call a WebApi method from my MVC app:

```
var model = new ExpandoObject(); // or use a stronly typed class.
model.Id = 1,
model.Name = "foo"

var http = new HttpClient();
http.Post("url", model, HttpContentTypes.ApplicationJson);
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin, what about calling this method from the mvc app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to respond with httpstaus code you have to return HttpResponseMessage.

You may choose to have a common method returning your BOs and call it from the Action and from your other mvc application code. Then your rest calls would always be wrapped with a status code and other calls get an object.

```
[HttpPut]
public MyModel Update(MyModel model)
{
    return base.Request.CreateResponse<MyModel>(HttpStatusCode.OK, UpdateModel(model));;
}

[NonAction]
internal MyModel UpdateModel(MyModel model)
{
    //make update
    return model;
}
```